# tfs build processes are slow and takes long time to finish

Tags: msbuild, build-process, build-automation, build-definition

If I Build my solution from VS, it takes less than a minute to do all the checks to tell me all the projects have been built. If I do the same in team foundation build, it takes closer to 20 minutes.
i define as "items to build" only the solution (.sln file) and solution has 32 "projects".

Answer (score 3):

Check the build definition workspace, make sure you are only pulling doen the code you need for the build.

Also TFS does a clean compile, I.e. it pulls down all of the code then rebuilds everything from scratch. How long does a clean build take locally? Less than a minute to build 32 projects seems quick so I suspect that your local build is incremental rather than full.

Run a build with diangnostic loging, this should give you a clue to the parts that are taking the time.

Comment: Then there used to be a sln.cache file (or similar) that kept track of some project ordering?  Like, it wouldn't be there the first time, but would be there later.  A "clean" TFS build wouldn't have the order.